# Form is not populated from rest response with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, checkbox

I am new to AngularJS and I am a little confused with it. I have to do a page with a few configuration options, that I want to save and when I open the page again the inputs have to be populated with the saved value. I have one check box and when it's value is false, all other fields are disabled. I did the saving and it works, but when I load the page after that, the inputs are disabled and empty. I am doing GET request on ng-init and than I am setting the scope variable of every input. They stay disabled, the checkbox is unchecked even when the ng-model for this checkbox is set to true by the response. ng-checked is the same, not visible. When I check the checkbox, magically the values are visible with the proper values. This is the html.

```
<div ng-controller="archivingController" ng-init="getArchivingOptions()">
<form name="archivingForm" ng-submit="saveConfiguration()" novalidate>
    <div id="archivingFormEnable">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" ng-model="configurations.enableArchiving"/>
        <label id="archivingLabelEnable">Enable Archiving</label>
    </div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Archiving Settings</legend>
        <div id="globalArchivingDiv">
            <label id="globalArchivingLabel" style="width: 240px">Global archiving:</label>
            <select ng-init="configurations.globalArchiving='disabled'" ng-model="configurations.globalArchiving" ng-disabled="!configurations.enableArchiving">
                <option value="disabled">Disabled</option>
                <option value="enabled">Enabled</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="archiveFolderDiv">
            <label id="archiveFolderLabel">Archive folder:</label>
            <input type="text" ng-disabled="!configurations.enableFileArchiving" ng-model="configurations.archiveFolder" required/>
            <span ng-show="fileArchivingForm.archiveFolder.$invalid && configurations.enableFileArchiving">Required.</span>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <button id="save" ng-disabled="fileArchivingForm.$invalid && configurations.enableFileArchiving">Save</button>
</form>
</div>
```

And the controller.

```
mainApp.controller('archivingController', ['$scope', function($scope){
$scope.getArchivingOptions = function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: someURL,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType : 'json', 
        cache: false,
        success : function(data) { 
            $scope.configurations = data.configurations;
        }
    });
}

$scope.saveConfiguration = function(){
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        contentType : 'application/json',
        url : someURL,
        dataType : 'json',
        data : JSON.stringify($scope.configurations),
        complete : function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            //some msg
        }
    });     
}
}]);
```

Actually I am sure that all of them are set, because when I call 
`console.log($scope.configurations.archiveFolder);` the value that is printed is correct as the one from the response. The problem is that it is not visible till I click the checkbox. I do not know what to do. I am open for suggestions. Thank you in advance.

Comment: why are you using $.ajax instead of $http?

Comment: There were some problems in he past with the http, but I will try with http too. Thank you.

Comment: It works with $http. The problem with it is when using IE9/10 but since the MS dropped the support, I will. Now the problem is that only the checkbox is not updated. The value is correct but visibly it is unchecked. There is no check in the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use jquery's $.ajax instead of angular's $http, you need to wrap the callbacks in a $scope.$apply:

```
"success": function(data) {
   $scope.$apply(function() {
       //your code here
   });
}
```

Comment: I've tried $http and it works. We had problem with it and IE9/10, but now since MS dropped the support of them, I can use $http. Now all inputs are populated except one, the check box. When I load the page I is uncheckd, but the other inputs are not disabled and they are correct. Thank you.